# Case-insensitive C locale

Tags: sort, locale

I'm trying to create a custom locale for use with the LC_COLLATE variable which sorts text just like the C locale, with the only exception that it sorts case-insensitively. I need this because I have lots of files with special (Japanese) characters in their names which just get scattered around randomly across the folder when using the en_US locale for LC_COLLATE. Setting LC_COLLATE to C fixes this issue; however, it introduces case-sensitivity which can get annoying when downloading files from the Internet which were named on the assumption that case wouldn't matter.

It was easy enough to create a custom locale based on the C locale which sorts AaBbCc... instead of ABC...abc... and this does alleviate the issue somewhat, but I can't figure out how to get it to treat uppercase and lowercase Latin letters as the same character while sorting as it does with the en_US locale (based on what I'm seeing in the iso14651_t1_common file it does look more complicated than I'd hope). 
So how do I do that last step?

(I know there are file managers that offer the option to ignore case, but I'd prefer not having to ditch a program just because it lacks this option (as many do).)

Comment: I think you've described the problem; are you asking for someone to develop a new locale *for you*?